# Find The Common Occurrences Of Words In Two String Values

Tags: javascript, regex, arrays

Suppose I have two strings which may look like below

```
var tester = "hello I have to ask you a doubt";
var case   = "hello better explain me the doubt";
```

This case both strings contains common word such as `hello` and `doubt`. So lets say my default string is `tester` and I have a variable `case` and it holds set of words that can be any thing. And I do wanna achieve the common words count which present in both `tester` and `case`. And it should give me a result in the form of an object.

**Result**

```
{"hello" : 1, "doubt" : 1};
```

My current implementation is like below

```
var tester = "hello I have to ask you a doubt";
function getMeRepeatedWordsDetails(case){
    var defaultWords = tester.split(" ");
    var testWords    = case.split(" "), result = {};
    for(var testWord in testWords){
        for(var defaultWord in defaultWords){
            if(defaultWord == testWord){
                result[testWord] = (!result[testWord]) ? 1 : (result[testWord] + 1);  
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

As I suspect there are Regex to make this task easier since it can find the pattern matches. But not sure this can be achieved using Regex. I need to know did I'm following the right path to do the same.

Comment: So if `"hello"` appears once in `tester` and twice in `case` should the count be 1 or 2?

Comment: It should be counting as two

Comment: And what about if it appears twice in both strings?  Or twice in `tester` and once in `case`?

Comment: And the reason for using `for...in` for a standard array is... ? Also you should use `result.hasOwnProperty(testWord)` instead of `!result[testWord]` for your if statement.

Comment: @ExplosionPills the String tester will remain same the duplicate occurrence of words in tester doesn't matter. Find all the words from tester and find the number of occurrence this in case string

Answer (score 5):

You can use a first regular expression as a tokenizer to split the `tester` string into a list of words, then use such words to build a second regular expression that matches the word list. For example:

```
var tester = "a string with a lot of words";

function getMeRepeatedWordsDetails ( sentence ) {
  sentence = sentence + " ";
  var regex = /[^\s]+/g;
  var regex2 = new RegExp ( "(" + tester.match ( regex ).join ( "|" ) + ")\\W", "g" );
  matches = sentence.match ( regex2 );
  var words = {};
  for ( var i = 0; i < matches.length; i++ ) {
    var match = matches [ i ].replace ( /\W/g, "" );
    var w = words [ match ];
    if ( ! w )
      words [ match ] = 1;
    else
      words [ match ]++;
  }   
  return words;
} 

console.log ( getMeRepeatedWordsDetails ( "another string with some words" ) );
```

The tokenizer is the line:

```
var regex = /[^\s]+/g;
```

When you do:

```
tester.match ( regex )
```

you get the list of words contained in `tester`:

```
[ "a", "string", "with", "a", "lot", "of", "words" ]
```

With such an array we build a second regular expression that matches all the words; `regex2` has the form:

```
/(a|string|with|a|lot|of|words)\W/g
```

The `\W` is added to match only whole words, otherwise the `a` element will match any word beginning with `a`. The result of applying `regex2` to `sentence` is another array with only the words that are contained in `regex2`, that is the words that are contained both in `tester` and `sentence`. Then the `for` loop only counts the words in the `matches` array transforming it into the object you requested.

But beware that:

- you have to put at least a space at the end of `sentence` otherwise the `\W` in `regex2` doesn't match the last word: `sentence = sentence + " "`
- you have to remove some possible extra character form the matches that has been captured by the `\W`: `match = matches [ i ].replace ( /\W/g, "" )`

Comment: I woudl be glad for your input converting this to VB.net at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22367155/find-the-common-occurrences-of-words-in-two-strings-regex

Comment: you should add \b at the beginning of the regex2 - great solution.