# Find The Common Occurrences Of Words In Two Strings Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, vb.net

I'm trying to do the same thing as: [Find The Common Occurrences Of Words In Two Strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22365397/find-the-common-occurrences-of-words-in-two-string-values/22366241#22366241) But I want it in VB.net.

```
var tester = "a string with a lot of words";

function getMeRepeatedWordsDetails ( sentence ) {
  sentence = sentence + " ";
  var regex = /[^\s]+/g;
  var regex2 = new RegExp ( "(" + tester.match ( regex ).join ( "|" ) + ")\\W", "g" );
  matches = sentence.match ( regex2 );
  var words = {};
  for ( var i = 0; i < matches.length; i++ ) {
    var match = matches [ i ].replace ( /\W/g, "" );
    var w = words [ match ];
    if ( ! w )
      words [ match ] = 1;
    else
      words [ match ]++;
  }   
  return words;
} 

console.log ( getMeRepeatedWordsDetails ( "another string with some words" ) );
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
    Dim tester As String = "a string with a lot of words"
    sentence = sentence & " "
    Dim regex As New Regex("/[^\s]+/g")
    Dim m As Match = regex.Match(tester)

    'not working
    Dim regex2 As Regex = New Regex("(" + regex.Match(tester).join("|") + ")\\W", "g")
```

Can you help me put this into VB.net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out:

```
    'string of interest
    Dim sentence As String = "check this string with some words"
    sentence = sentence & " "

    'this is our base string
    Dim BaseStr As String = "base string with a lot of words"

    'use this one liner to create the pattern
    Dim pattern2 As String = "(" & BaseStr.Replace(" ", "|") & ")\W"

    'set up the regex
    Dim regex As New Regex(pattern2)
    Dim mc As MatchCollection
    mc = regex.Matches(sentence)

    'loop to get the results
    For ct As Integer = 0 To mc.Count - 1
        Dim m As Match = mc.Item(ct)
        If m.Success Then
            'returns two groups; get the second without a space
            Debug.Print(m.Groups(1).Captures(0).ToString() & "<<")
        End If
    Next
```